# Disabling link on Magento nav

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, menu, navigation, topmenu

I am trying to disable the top links on my Magento nav. I want the dropdown to show but I would like the top link to not link anywhere. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: you can do using js

Comment: How? Can you please help?

Comment: url please so i can check

Comment: it's not live at the moment, local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check below js code

> jQuery('li.level0 a.level0 ').click(function(e) {
>   e.preventDefault()});

for magento 2:- 
jQuery('li.level0 a.level-top ').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault()});

you can add into console of crome and you can check code is working

Comment: Where would I place this code?

Comment: i think you need to knowledge about that, you need to add into js file after jQuery load

Answer (score 0):

/home/sis118/Desktop/Loader.gif